# Why is the assembler using FS:40

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

When I initialize an array in c, the assembly code generated by gcc adds a line that looks like this:

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what fs:40 is doing. In gdb the fs pointer is pointing to zero:

```
(gdb) i r fs
fs             0x0  0
```

So based on [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64) the first 128 bytes is just garbage. So why is it copying 8 bytes of garbage after the array?

This is my code:

```
int main(){
    char buffer[8];
}
```

This is how I compiled it into intel assembly format:

```
 gcc -S -O0 -masm=intel ch2.c -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
```

This is the output assembly file I get. I'm only showing the "Main" function area:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16
    mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:40   ;;<<< this is the line
    mov QWORD PTR -8[rbp], rax
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, 0
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR -8[rbp]
    xor rdx, QWORD PTR fs:40
    je  .L4
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L4:
    leave
    ret
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a [stack cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries)

Comment: Also, `fs` being zero doesn't matter, 64 bit segmentation works differently and it isn't a pointer anyway.